# Pythonic Way to Initialize Boolean

Tags: python, initialization, boolean

I would like to know your preferred way to initialize a boolean. I can't find any good reason for one of the solutions by my own.

After the initialization I use isLastInMonth in a loop and don't want to call monthrange any time!

Example 1:

```
if monthrange(2015, 5)[1] == today.day:
    isLastInMonth = True
else:
    isLastInMonth = False
```

Example 2:

```
isLastInMonth = False
if monthrange(2015, 5)[1] == today.day:
    isLastInMonth = True
```

**Edit:**

It seems like you prefer a third one:

Example 3:

```
isLastInMonth = monthrange(2015, 5)[1] == today.day
```

Some Answers refer to my old example:

Example 1:

```
if fooA == True:
    fooB = True
else:
    fooB = False
```

Example 2:

```
fooB = False
if fooA == True:
    fooB = True
```

Comment: Why not just assign `fooB = fooA`?

Comment: What about `fooA = fooB` - `fooB` appears to be boolean as well?

Comment: Before worrying about Pythonic ways to initialise `fooB`, perhaps you should look up the Pythonic way to test `fooA` (hint: that isn't it)?

Comment: Okay, maybe i cut down my example too much! I have edit my question!

Comment: Then why not `isLastInMonth = (monthrange(2015, 5)[1] == today.day)`?

Comment: I use isLastInMonth in a loop and don't want to call monthrange any time.

Comment: The line I've suggested calls `monthrange` *exactly as many times* as your two examples. Please clarify the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Given a condition (fooA), initialize fooB:

```
>>> fooB = fooA
```

And complement:

```
>>> fooB = not fooA
```

So, for your example:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> from calendar import monthrange
>>>
>>>
>>> isLastInMonth = monthrange(2015,5)[1] == date.today()
```

I wouldn't hard code 2015 or 5, but I guess this is just an example.

Comment: His two examples. Initializing to "the same value as the condition", and "to the complement of the condition"

Comment: Ah, I misread the second example. Anyway, I will leave my second example there, to avoid OP using if statements for this.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is equivalent to:

```
fooB = fooA
```

Answer (score 2):

I like `fooB = fooA`:

```
In [16]: fooA = True

In [17]: fooB = fooA

In [18]: fooB
Out[18]: True

In [19]: fooA = False

In [20]: fooB
Out[20]: True
```

---

to match the edit:

```
isLastInMonth = monthrange(2015, 5)[1] == today.day
```

Comment: I use isLastInMonth in a loop and don't want to call monthrange any time.

Comment: Using isLastInMonth in a loop will not cause monthrange to be called again. `isLastInMonth = monthrange(2015, 5)[1] == today.day` will call monthrange once, get the element at index 1 compare it to today.day then set isLastMonth in range to either True or False.